# Showing an image as an overlay on top of 2 rows

Tags: css, css-grid

Here using the **CSS grid system** want to **overlay** an image like a logo with a **margin** on right **on top of 2 divs**.
I can guess there should be more than one approach, I'm eager to know what method do you suggest, and please provide a live example.

div1 and div2 should **fill the entire width with a little margin**.
The image will have some transparency and also will have a margin over the right side, e.g **80px**.

*The code that I tried is like below, at this point not doing its job:*

```css
.c1Wrap{
    display: grid;
    /* grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr; */
    grid-template-rows: 100px 100px;

}


.c1HeaderTop{
    grid-row: 1;
    background: #db4ea5;
}
.c1HeaderBottom{
    grid-row: 2;
    background: #831d5c;
}

.c1Logo {
    z-index: 101;
    grid-row: 1/2; 
    opacity: 0.6;
    grid-row: 1/2;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    right: 80px;
    background-color: #222;    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">    
</head>
<body>
<div class="c1Wrap">
    <div class="c1HeaderTop"></div>
    <div class="c1HeaderBottom"></div>
    <div class="c1Logo"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The desired look is attached, thanks for any help.

[image: An image overlayed over 2 rows]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is by overlapping cells, also we need to define the columns.
It will give us the exact result.

```css
.c1Wrap{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 100px 100px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 200px;
}

.c1HeaderTop{
    grid-row: 1;
    grid-column: 1/4;
    background: #db4ea5;
}
.c1HeaderBottom{
    grid-row: 2;
    background: #831d5c;
    grid-column: 1/4;
}

.c1Logo {
    z-index: 101;
    grid-row: 1/3;
    grid-column: 3;
    opacity: 0.6;
    background-color: rgb(134, 133, 133);    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    
</head>
<body>
<div class="c1Wrap">
    <div class="c1HeaderTop"></div>
    <div class="c1HeaderBottom"></div>
    <div class="c1Logo">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you can do that only with CSS-grid. It can be easily done by using absolute positioning:

```css
.c1Wrap{
    display: grid;
    /* grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr; */
    grid-template-rows: 100px 100px;
    position: relative;
}


.c1HeaderTop{
    grid-row: 1;
    background: #db4ea5;
}
.c1HeaderBottom{
    grid-row: 2;
    background: #831d5c;
}

.c1Logo {
    z-index: 101;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    opacity: 0.6;
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;

    background-color: #222;    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">    
</head>
<body>
<div class="c1Wrap">
    <div class="c1HeaderTop"></div>
    <div class="c1HeaderBottom"></div>
    <div class="c1Logo"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks mentioning that, I tried to avoid absolute positioning, I guess it can be done by the CSS grid itself.